# How to convert `project.android` Groovy syntax to Kotlin within a Gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, plugins, kotlin

I have a gradle plugin written in `Groovy` and want to convert it to `Kotlin`.

In the plugin class I have a function:

```
private static getAndroidVariants(Project project) {
        (project.android.hasProperty("libraryVariants") ? project.android.libraryVariants : project.android.applicationVariants)
}
```

which returns the build variants of an android application/library.

How would I convert `project.android` to `Kotlin` syntax?

```
project.extensions.getByName("android") as LibraryExtension).libraryVariants
```

always returns an empty array from Kotlin but actually a filled list from groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used the wrong iterator on the returned value when moving to `Kotlin`.

Instead of `foreach`, one needs to use `all` for those type of containers.